# Capistrano 3 Deploy via a Copy

Tags: deployment, copy, capistrano3

**set :deploy_via, :copy** has been removed from Cap 3.

In case you have no Internet access on production server you may had have a hard time.
There is nice Gem [capistrano-scm-copy](https://github.com/wercker/capistrano-scm-copy) can copy your folder to production server. But it won't justify which is your release branch.

Is there a **Gem** can **copy and deploy** a **specific branch** to server, just like the old day?
I am using **Capistrano 3**.

Answer (score 3):

## [capistrano-scm-gitcopy](https://github.com/xuwupeng2000/capsitrano-scm-gitcopy)

Capistrano 3 :copy

A copy strategy for Capistrano 3, which mimics the `:copy` scm of Capistrano 2.
This Gem is inspired by and based on https://github.com/wercker/capistrano-scm-copy.
Thank wercker so much.

This will make Capistrano tar the a specific git branch, upload it to the server(s) and then extract it in the release directory.

## Requirements

Machine running Capistrano:

- Capistrano 3
- tar

Servers:

- mktemp
- tar

## Installation

First make sure you install the capistrano-scm-gitcopy by adding it to your `Gemfile`:

```
gem "capistrano-scm-gitcopy"
```

Then switch the `:scm` option to `:gitcopy` in `config/deploy.rb`:

```
set :scm, :gitcopy
```

## Usage

`bash
  cap uat deploy -s branch=(your release branch)`

Comment: Seems to be deprecated for Capistrano 3.8.1: https://github.com/xuwupeng2000/capistrano-scm-gitcopy/issues/48

Comment: Does not work anymore :(